# How can I use monospaced font inside a matrix (or tabular etc)?

Tags: fonts, matrices, arrays

I would like to display a matrix with characters using monospaced font (as in `\tt` and `\mathtt`), but I haven't found an easy way to do it. Something like this:

```
\begin{center}{\tt\left(
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  A & B & C & D\\
  E & F & G & H\\
  I & J & K & L
\end{tabular}\right)}.
\end{center}
```

But this won't work, because I used `\left(` and `\right)` outside math environment.

```
\[
{\mathtt
\begin{pmatrix}
  A & B & C & D\\
  E & F & G & H\\
  I & J & K & L
\end{pmatrix}
}
\]
```

This one won't work either:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

I know I can do this by using `{\mathtt A} & {\mathtt B}`, and so on, for each matrix element, but that would be really a pain (I have more matrices).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use the `tabular` environment inside a math group; instead, use the (very similar) `array` environment.

The following example code uses the `newcolumntype` command of the `array` package to create the `t` column type, which typesets its contents in monospaced font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\tt}c}
\begin{document}
\[ \left( \begin{array}{tttt}
  A & B & C & D\\
  E & F & G & H\\
  I & J & K & L
\end{array} \right) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\left(` and `\right)` parentheses around the matrix, you could also use `\left[` and `\right]` for square brackets, `\left\{` and `\right\}` for curly braces, and `\left\lvert` and `\right\rvert` for straight lines, to name a few possibilities.

Comment: Never recommend the obsolete command `\tt`. Why shouldn't it be a good idea to use `tabular` in math mode?

Comment: I didn't know `\tt` was obsolete. What should I use instead? (I use `\tt` a lot in my documents!)

Comment: @Jay [`l2tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu) is a good source for obsolete commands, including this.

Comment: @egreg -- I *know* that `\tt` is deprecated. However, it's more straightforward to define the `t` column type using `\tt` for an array than with `\ttfamily`, which requires text mode. At least two good reasons for reserving use of the `tabular` and `array` environments for text and math modes, respectively: (i) the "standard" column types such as `l`, `c`, and `r` behave differently in text and math mode. Recall that the OP is trying to define a *matrix* and not some general two-dimensional array of text entries. (ii) the `\tabcolsep` and `\arraycolsep` length variables aren't the same.

Comment: @Mico Some classes don't even define `\tt`.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know that some classes don't even define `\tt`. Can you give some examples? I'm curious now.

Answer (score 7):

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\ttfamily}c}

\[
\left(\begin{tabular}{tttt}
  A & B & C & D\\
  E & F & G & H\\
  I & J & K & L
\end{tabular}\right)
\]
```

A `tabular` is quite good also in math mode. With `\newcolumntype{t}{>{\ttfamily}c}` you define a column made by centered cells typeset in typewriter type.

Comment: Thank you -- but I get `! LaTeX Error: Command \ttfamily invalid in math mode.` with that...

Comment: @Jay Did you copy correctly? The inner environment is `tabular`, not `array` as in Mico's answer.

Comment: Ops... I changed one of the matrices to tabular, but there was another on left as array. Now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Jay: Be aware that if you mix matrices typeset with `array` and `tabular` environments, the two will have different column widths -- unless you issue a command such as `\setlength\tabcolsep\arraycolsep` (a setting you probably don't want to have apply globally as it will otherwise affect "real", i.e., text-mode `tabular` environments as well).